# count of unique occurrences of a value pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

So I have an extremely simple dataframe:

```
values
1
1
1
2
2
```

I want to add a new column and for each row assign the sum of it's unique occurences, so the table would look like:

```
values unique_sum
1 3
1 3
1 3
2 2
2 2
```

I have seen some examples in R, but for python and pandas I have not come across anything and am stuck. I can list the value counts using `.value_counts()` and I have tried `groupby`routines but cannot fathom it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `map` to map your column onto its `value_counts`:

```
>>> x
   A
0  1
1  1
2  1
3  2
4  2
>>> x['unique'] = x.A.map(x.A.value_counts())
>>> x
   A  unique
0  1       3
1  1       3
2  1       3
3  2       2
4  2       2
```

(I named the column `A` instead of `values`.  `values` is not a great choice for a column name, because DataFrames have a special attribute called `values`, which prevents you from getting the column with `x.values` --- you'd have to use `x['values']` instead.)

Comment: Fantastic. I need to investigate .map then. Thank you so much!