# Conditional function on multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `csv` file like so:

```
         Landform              Number         Name   Class
0        Deltaic Plain         912            Lx     NaN
1    Hummock and Swale         912            Lx     NaN
2           Sand Dunes         912            Lx     NaN
3    Hummock and Swale         939       Woodbury    NaN
4           Sand Dunes         939       Woodbury    NaN
```

and when Landform contains `Deltaic Plain`, `Hummock and Swale` and `Sand Dunes` for a particular `Name` I want to assign a value of 1 to `Class`.

When `Landform` is contains `Hummock and Swale` and `Sand Dunes` I want to assign a value of 2 for `Class`.

My desired output is:

```
         Landform              Number         Name   Class
0        Deltaic Plain         912            Lx     1
1    Hummock and Swale         912            Lx     1
2           Sand Dunes         912            Lx     1
3    Hummock and Swale         939       Woodbury    2
4           Sand Dunes         939       Woodbury    2
```

I know how to do this for just 1 row like this:

```
def f(x):
  if x['Landform'] == 'Hummock and Swale' : return '1'
  else: return '2'

df['Class'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

but I am not sure how to group by `Name` and then create the conditional functions based on numerous rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to group on your Number column, and apply a function that looks at all the landforms in that group and returns an appropriate class.  Here's an example:

```
def determineClass(landforms):
    if all(form in landforms.values for form in ('Deltaic Plain', 'Hummock and Swale', 'Sand Dunes')):
        return 1
    elif all(form in landforms.values for form in ('Hummock and Swale', 'Sand Dunes')):
        return 2
    # etc.
    else:
        # return "default" class
        return 0

>>> df.groupby('Number').Landform.apply(determineClass)
Number
912    1
939    2
Name: Landform, dtype: int64
```

If you want to assign the values back into the Class column, just use `map`, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842544/count-of-unique-occurrences-of-a-value-pandas-python/34842657#34842657) from 20 minutes ago:

```
>>> classes = df.groupby('Number').Landform.apply(determineClass)
>>> df['Class'] = df.Number.map(classes)
>>> df
            Landform  Number      Name  Class
0      Deltaic Plain     912        Lx      1
1  Hummock and Swale     912        Lx      1
2         Sand Dunes     912        Lx      1
3  Hummock and Swale     939  Woodbury      2
4         Sand Dunes     939  Woodbury      2
```

Comment: how would I edit this code so if `Name` has only 1 `Landform` the code still runs?  e.g. `def determineClass(landforms):
    if all(form in landforms.values for form in ('Deltaic Plain')):
        return 1`  I think I need to change `all` to something else for this.

Comment: @StefanoPotter: It already will run if there is only one value, it will just assign 0 as the class.  You need to write `determineClass` to do whatever logic you want it to do.  Your question doesn't explain what you want it to do if there is only one landform, so you'll have to decide that yourself.  For instance, if you want to check for "Sand Dunes" you could do `if "Sand Dunes" in landforms.values`